# How do I get the index in a TemplateCollectionView?

Tags: sproutcore, handlebars.js

So I followed the [sproutcore "getting started" guide](http://guides.sproutcore.com/getting_started.html), and started wandering off the path to see if I could do what I meant easily. And here I am witht this templates, that represents a list of file inputs :

```
{{#collection SC.TemplateCollectionView 
  contentBinding="Upload.uploadListController"}}
   <label>{{content.title}}</label><input type="file" name="upload[]"/>
{/collection}}
```

Nice. Now what I'd like to do is benefit from the label `for` attribute to point to the corresponding input. So basically, I'd like to output something like this:

```
<label for="upload-0">Some label</label>
<input id="upload-0" type="file" name="upload[]"/>

<label for="upload-1">Some otherlabel</label>
<input id="upload-1" type="file" name="upload[]"/>
<!-- you get it -->
```

How do I do that? I did not find the answer neither on the [using handlebars page](http://guides.sproutcore.com/using_handlebars.html) nor on the [sproutcore documentation on SC.ArrayController](http://docs.sproutcore.com/#doc=SC.ArrayController&method=content&src=false)

Am I looking in the wrong place? Am I trying to do something I should do in another, more sproutcore-ish way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see to do this is adding an *id* field in your model. 
So you could use this id in the template.

```
{{#collection SC.TemplateCollectionView contentBinding="Upload.uploadListController"}}
   <label {{bindattr for="content.id"}} >{{content.title}}</label>
   <input {{bindattr id="content.id"}} type="file" name="upload[]"/>
{{/collection}}
```

Comment: I tried this, but sproutcore wraps the output of `{{content.id}}` with span tags. How can I prevent this?

Comment: You should use '{{bindAttr for="content-id"}}' if you want to bind to attributes.